# Terminal: How to MKDIR multiple directories with different names and auto increment

Tags: bash, terminal

I need to create multiple directories with mkdir in Terminal with auto-increment:
`mkdir "apples" "bananas" "oranges"` ... etc. Resulting folders should have auto increment at the beginning of each folder: `1 apples`, `2 bananas`, `3 oranges`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

fruits=(apples bananas oranges)
i=1

for fruit in "${fruits[@]}"
do
    mkdir "$i $fruit"
    (( ++i ))
done
```

Comment: thanks, that did it

Comment: @jaed Great! You're welcome!